# Can someone make a new badge for me?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

Can someone make a new badge?
1st answer on year old question  "Thank you"

I just 1st answered this year old question [Android how to get filename from email attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379057/how-to-get-filename-and-extension-when-opening-email-attachment/18426982#18426982) Over a year and not even an attempt at the answer and I answered with a solution that works for preview and downloaded attachments.  IDK seems to be pretty important feature for your app when you implement sharing to know the attachment filename.

Comment: There's already two badges for that: revival & necromancer.

Comment: Can we make a badge that awards users for removing "Thanks" and such?

Comment: P.s the whole MIT license thing holds no ground really. All content you post is licensed [CC-BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). And please don't put conditions on your answers such as "for a big bounty I'll do X"

Comment: @Bart correct.  However, what if I add an exception to the license? Like the GNU C runtime does so it can be GNU GPL _and_ be linked to non-GPL modules.

Comment: @ColeJohnson No expert, but it's true that you can release content under multiple licenses. In this case the OP is free to release it under an MIT license in addition to the CC-BY-SA license.

Comment: @Bart doing that requires you to follow _both_ licenses. That means if anything is contradictory between the two, then you _can't_, no matter what, combine them. Like the 4 clause BSD and the GPL. The advertising clause in the 4-BSD contradicts the definition of "free" in the GPL.

Comment: Ok, OP: I don't really understand your proposed definition: "First answer on year old question 'Thank you'". Are you defining it as the first answer on a year old question? Or the first answer on a year old question with a "Thanks" signature? We already try to remove the "thanks" signatures, so if the system can't figure out to remove it or not, how would it know whether to award the badge or not?

Comment: So then, @Cole, one cannot add the extra MIT license to the post? *"You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, even if [...]"*

Comment: @Arjan IANAL, but if there is even _one_ clause that contradicts, you can't.

Comment: I read all the badges.  This person sat for a year and was probably somewhat active on the site.  Something I had a recent success in accomplishing gave a working example that I have in a production app.  No one on earth could help them but me.  It's a year old question where was the community?

Comment: *"No one on earth could help them but me."* ... meh, that's probably a significant exaggeration of the situation. A question slipped through the cracks and wasn't brought to the attention of the community in a significant manner. Can happen. Great that you answered it, but no reason for a new badge in addition to some of the badges we already have, as stated in the answers below.

Comment: Yes I agree to the site license.  The code I posted was already under a MIT license I had an obligation with my original accord to bring the license with the code.  Just keep my name with it all that I ask.

Comment: You can release code under two licenses. It is done all the time. The user of the code just has to *pick one*. They cannot combine terms of multiple licenses to create a custom one.

Comment: Indeed, that's my understanding as well @CodyGray.

Comment: As for badges, you almost got the [peer pressure](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) badge instead :-( (That would have needed another downvote though.)

Comment: I was thinking like "Archeologist untouched"   or maybe can I get this question to minus 50.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We don't really support (allow) making badges here. There has to be a valid reason to make one. If I read your question correctly, there are *already* two badges similar to what you describe. The first is [Revival](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival):

> Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

The other is Revival's older brother, [Necromancer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer):

> Answered a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Comment: So only the founders make badges.  There is no community involvement.

Comment: @danny117 I said "we don't _really_" and "there has to be a valid reason". What that means is that there has to be a proposal that people agree with. We don't just go willy nillly making badges for people.